# Sending a POST request with php on itself

Tags: php, post

I have an application which lightly follow an MVC model. It got 3 main pages (some are not important for the question):

1. a PHP Framework build in OOP (implements users, filestream, an mailing pear module, etc)
2. A process page that instanciate the objects needed for the application. The page is call Process.php
3. a HTML page to display all the informations that Process.php uses.

The problem:

Process.php create a POST request (see following code) that send a request to itself using static URL. I would like to know if there is a way to change it to a relative URL.

Code for Process.php:

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtFCUCompName'], ENT_QUOTES);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pwdFCUPwd'], ENT_QUOTES);
$confirmation = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pwdFCUConf'], ENT_QUOTES);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtFCUEml'], ENT_QUOTES);
$_SESSION['msg'] = "";

/*Sending a POST request trought PHP to use this page to validate the fields in php in case the clients javascript module is disabled.*/
//!!!!!!!!!This line is the problem!!!!!!!!!
$url = "http://someadresse.com/somefolder/Process.php";

$PostParams = array
(
    'NewUser' => array
    (
        'validate'=>'NewUser',
        'array'=>json_encode
        (
            array
            (
                "txtFCUCompName"=>$username,
                "txtFCUEml"=>$email,
                "pwdFCUPwd"=>$password,
                "pwdFCUConf"=>$confirmation
            )
        )
    )
    //More arrays.
);
//Loop through all the arrays inside the array of parameter and send a request for each one.    
foreach($PostParams as $index=>$Params)
{
    $PostOptions = array
    (
        "http"=>array
        (
            "header"=>"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            "method"=>"POST",
            "content"=>http_build_query($Params)
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($PostOptions);
    $_SESSION['msg'] = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);//LINE 1502 (see error code below)
}

if($_SESSION['msg'] == null)
{
    //Do stuff with the returned values of the post request...    
}
header("Location: SoumissionJRT.php");
//I have another section of Process.php that do some validation and echo HTML div tags with text.
```

More information:

The problem is that Process.php could change folder from time to time (once per year maybe) and I dont want to have to change the hardcoded `$url` variable everytime. The request is always going to point to the same page it is originate from.

Dont misunderstand the question, the problem isn't the POST request itself but the URL to which it is sent. The POST work just fine.

I HAVE TRIED just changing it to `$url = "../Process.php"` and `$url = "."` but nothing I change `$url` to seems to be working. It doesn't display an error message on browsers but in the PHP errorlogs file I have the following error

> [09-Apr-2014 16:15:33] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(.): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\somefolder\Process.php on line 1502

AND

> [09-Apr-2014 16:16:10] PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(../Process.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\somefolder\Process.php on line 1502

LINE 1502 point to

```
$_SESSION[$key] = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Furhtermore, I am not stupid I do understand that `file_get_contents()` doesn't find the requested URL or that this one doesn't exist inside my application directory.

EDIT:
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] doesn't work, it return this value:

```
/somefolder/Process.php
```

it seems the request need a complete URL to Process.php.
but maybe there is another `$_SERVER[]` that contains the required adress?

Or, maybe I will need to concatenate 2 or 3 of them?

Anyone know a work around or a fixe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you can just use

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This will always get you the location of the currently running script.

Comment: Doesn't work... check EDITED question for explaination. It still gives me the unable to open stream no such file in directory error as seen in the question.

Comment: @Sebastien You are clearly confused.  Why would you try to read the content of a PHP file from inside that same PHP file?  You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: I dont think the logic is the problem here. But putting that aside, questionning the logic behind my code without knowing the context in which it was made, doesn't help me find an answer.

Comment: I used this line of code to fix my problem:`$url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` I'll give you the answer as you provide the basics to achieve what I want.